Filter pdf with python
Ive been trying to find an answer by myself but the way how I want it was never found sadly, so I have a PDF file which contains multiple different pdf file, I want to create a python code (with venv) which is gonna filter pdf files with pages
for example:

Client wants to filter his pdf file (The interface will be like IlovePdf web-site)
He clicks upload file
Then chooses from which to which page he wants to filter (like from 1-13, from 14-20, from 21-25)
Then new files that are filtered will be downloading in the folder

Then code filters this file and then gives those filtered files to download
This all is gonna be like an app in the computers therefore I will need to create an interface which I will do on my own (at least I will try to)
I tried to use glob and didnt actualy helped me, then I installed venv into my python project and thats it
import glob, os

folder_path = 'C:\\work\\PythonPDF'

os.chdir(folder_path)
files = [file for file in glob.glob("*.pdf")]
files = [file for file in files if file.__contains__('Conlclusion')]
print(files)

Thats one of the examples but it filters with a word I need with a pages
import fitz

def extract_pdfs(input_pdf_path, output_dir):
    document = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)
    pdf_count = 1
    new_pdf = fitz.open()

    for i in range(document.page_count):
        page = document.load_page(i)
        page_text = page.get_text("text")

        if "Abstract" in page_text:
            if new_pdf.page_count > 0:
                new_pdf.save(f"{output_dir}/extracted_pdf_{pdf_count}.pdf")
                pdf_count += 1
            new_pdf = fitz.open()

        new_pdf.insert_pdf(document, from_page=i, to_page=i)

    if new_pdf.page_count > 0:
        new_pdf.save(f"{output_dir}/extracted_pdf_{pdf_count}.pdf")

    print(f"Извлечено {pdf_count} отдельных PDF файлов.")

    input_pdf = r"C:\work\PythonPDF\Filter.pdf"
    output_directory = r"C:\work\PythonPDF\AllPdf"

    extract_pdfs(input_pdf, output_directory)

As you can see it filters with the word Abstract but I need with pages :(
Thank you!

trying to ask this question again since stackoverflow doesnt want me to post it somehow :(

Have you tried PyPDF2? I found it much more intuitive and easier to use. PyPDF2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To split a PDF file by specific page ranges, you can use the PyMuPDF library (also known as fitz) which is excellent for handling PDFs. Here’s a Python script that takes an input PDF and page ranges, extracts the specified pages, and saves each range as a new PDF. This example doesn’t use glob, as that’s mainly for finding files by name or extension, not for splitting pages.
To help you out, I’ll break down the code, including the core logic of loading the PDF, extracting pages based on ranges, and saving them. Here’s a sample script for the page range filtering:
Setting Up the Virtual Environment and Dependencies
Create a virtual environment in your project directory:
python -m venv venv
Activate the virtual environment:
On Windows:
\venv\Scripts\activate
On Mac/Linux:
\venv\Scripts\activate
Install PyMuPDF:
pip install pymupdf
Explanation of the Code
extract_pages_by_ranges function:
    input_pdf_path: Path to the input PDF file.
    page_ranges: List of tuples representing the start and end pages for each range, e.g., [(1, 13), (14, 20)].
    output_dir: Directory where the filtered PDF files will be saved.

Looping through the page ranges:
    For each page range, a new PDF is created.
    Each page specified in the range is added to this new PDF.
    The file is saved with a name indicating the range, like filtered_pages_1-13.pdf.

Saving each range as a separate file:
    After inserting pages for each range, the file is saved and closed.

Integrating with a User Interface
To create a user-friendly app with an interface similar to ILovePDF, consider using Tkinter or a more robust framework like PyQt or Kivy for the GUI. The function extract_pages_by_ranges can then be connected to a file upload button, a page range input, and a save/download button in the GUI.

thank you very much for the answer, I know its probably my problem but I couldnt find from the pymupdf documentation on how to "filter" with pages, if that would be possible for you to provide a code for the python, but still, your answer has helped me a lot already, thank you! With all love and respect!
